# Sequence of arithmetic means of a square summable sequence is square summable

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it true that if $x \in \ell^2$ then $\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)_{n} \in \ell^2$ ? I conjecture that this is false and the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\ln(n)}$ is a counterexample, but I cannot prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true by [Hardy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%27s_inequality) for $p=2$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2
\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|\right)^2
\stackrel{\text{Hardy}}{\leq}  4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|^2.$$

P.S. Your counterexample does not work: if $x_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\ln(n+1)}$ then, by [Stolz-Cesaro Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem),
$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{x_n}&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{nx_n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{(n+1)x_{n+1}-nx_n}\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n+1 - \frac{n(n+1)^{1/2}\ln(n+2)}{n^{1/2}\ln(n+1)}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n+1 - n(1+\frac{1}{2n})}=2,\end{align}$$
anf it follows that $\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)_{n} \in \ell^2$ because
$$\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2\sim (2x_n)^2=\frac{4}{n\ln^2(n+1)}.$$

Comment: @Andrei Kh In my P.S. see the reason why your counterexample does not work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why is the limit above equal to 2? I figured $\frac{x_{n+1}}{(n+1)y_{n+1} - ny_n} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{(n+1)^{1/2}\ln(n+1)}{n^{1/2}\ln(n+2)}}$

Comment: (The idea behind $x_n$ was that the sum grows like $\sqrt{n}$ (actually a litte less that that) and that the square of the mean grows like $\frac{1}{n}$ and thus is not summable)

Comment: I think I don't see something obvious, but isn't that limit equal to $\infty$, since $\frac{(n+1)^{1/2}\ln(n+1)}{n^{1/2}\ln(n+2)} \sim 1$ ?

Comment: I edited my P.S. with more details.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. I got confused by the $y_n$ in yhe denominator. Thank you!

Comment: To the proposer: I noticed right away that your proposed counter-example fails: $\sum_{j=2}^n(1/(\sqrt j\;\log j)\sim$ $\sim  \int_2^n(1/(\sqrt x \;\log x)dx=$ $\int_2^n(2/\log x )d\sqrt x=$ $ 2\sqrt n/\log n-2\sqrt 2\;/\log 2+\int_2^n1/(\sqrt x\;\log^2 x)dx\sim$ $ 2\sqrt n /\log n.$.... So $(1/n)\sum_{j=2}^n x_j\sim 2x_n$ in this example. To  Robert Z: +1